# Postgres arg min in a group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using Postgres 9.6, and I have the following data:

```
user, rank, color
Alice, 1, blue
Alice, 2, green
Bob, 2, blue
Bob, 1, red
```

I want my desired output to be:

```
user, top_color
Alice, blue
Bob, red
```

What I've tried:

```
WITH top_rank AS (
       SELECT "user", min(rank) AS rank FROM table GROUP BY user
),
SELECT "user", color 
FROM table 
JOIN top_rank on table.rank = top_rank.rank GROUP BY "user";
```

Is there a simpler way to do this (ideally 1 query, with an argmin like operator) or do I need to use 2 queries?

Comment: . . You have *one* query.  It happens to use a common table expression (CTE).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the simplest method is `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (user) user, color
from t
order by user, rank;
```